# Calculation of row differences with changing conditions in a data frame

Tags: r, dataframe, conditional-statements

Gidday,
I have a data frame that looks as follows:

```
> test[1:20,]
                companycode     year    expenses         reductions_to_year1
    1                 C1          1     8.47720                 NA
    2                 C1          2     8.45250                 NA
    3                 C1          3     8.46280                 NA
    4                 C2          1 14828.90603                 NA
    5                 C3          1   665.21565                 NA
    6                 C3          2   290.66596                 NA
    7                 C3          3   865.56265                 NA
    8                 C3          4   6785.03586                NA
    9                 C3          5   312.02617                 NA
    10                C3          6   760.48740                 NA
    11                C3          7  1155.76758                 NA
    12                C4          1  4565.78313                 NA
    13                C4          2  3340.36540                 NA
    14                C4          3  2656.73030                 NA
    15                C4          4  1079.46098                 NA
    16                C5          1    60.57039                 NA
    17                C6          1  6282.48118                 NA
    18                C6          2  7419.32720                 NA
    19                C7          1   644.90571                 NA
    20                C8          1 58332.34945                 NA
```

Short explanation:
C1 - C8 in $companycode are 8 different companies. Values in $year show the years for which data ($expenses) exists. Expenses are displayed in $expenses.

What I want to do is to calculate the yearly differences (in percentage) of the values in $expenses compared to the value of year 1 for each company. The calculated values should be displayed in $reductions_to_year1.

e.g. for row 1-3

```
             companycode     year    expenses         reductions_to_year1
 1                 C1          1     8.47720                 0.0000000
 2                 C1          2     8.45250                 0.2913698
 3                 C1          3     8.46280                 0.1698674
```

I calculate the values as follows (in %):

```
test[1,4]= 1-(test[1,3]/test[1,3]) # year 1, no difference
test[2,4]= 1-(test[2,3]/test[1,3]) # 0.2913698% difference to year 1 
test[3,4]= 1-(test[3,3]/test[1,3]) # 0.1698674% difference to year 1
```

The challenge (for me) is that this is a data frame with around 1000 rows, around 300 different companies (displayed as a sequence from "C1" to "C300") and data for several years (approx. 1-10).
I tried to write a loop, but struggled with the aspect that for each company the value of year 1 has to be used in order to calculate the differences.

To clarify, when a new company in $companycode occurs the expenses over the following years need to be compared to the expenses in year 1.

I know that looping for data frame is inefficient, that's why I thought that the functions tapply,apply,sapply etc. might be a good approach... Would be great if someone is keen to do it that way.

I hope it's clear and you guys can help me out.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In base R this is done with `ave`. I included the first line in case the `data.frame` that you have isn't already sorted by year. If it is then you can skip it because the function in `ave` relies on the `data.frame` being already sorted at least like you have it here.

```
dat <- dat[order(dat$year),] # or order(s$companycode, s$year) to make it like presented here
dat$reductions_to_year1 <- 
   ave(dat$expenses, dat$company, FUN = function(x) 100*(1 - x/x[1]))
```

But it would work even faster if you had made a vector with just the first year expenses.

```
exp1 <-  ave( dat$expenses, dat$company, FUN = '[', '1' )
```

Then you can just rely on good old vectorization.

```
dat$reductions_to_year1 <- 100*(1 - dat$expenses/exp1)
```

Comment: Concerning your ave() solution (first one):
What needs to be changed to compare the value  to the previous year instead of always to the first year?
Thanks for your time and help.

Comment: @ John
I thought it would be just adding an x-1 to the last term. (FUN = function(x) 100*(1 - x/x[x-1])). However, this leads to warning. I guess I need to define to start comparing to the previous year from year 2 on. I'm sadly not quite sure how to define that within the funciton.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the plyr package for this kind of task very simply. As pointed out in the comments, this depends on the data.frame being sorted by year:

```
library(plyr)
dat <- dat[order(dat$year),]
dat.out <- ddply(dat, .(companycode), transform, 
                 reductions_to_year1 = 100*(1 - (expenses/expenses[1])))
```

This breaks the data up into pieces based on `companycode`, then performs the operation on each piece. I'm not sure if I've matched what you wanted done in the calculation, but you can make any calculation on each piece that you want.

Comment: It's important to note that the data.frame has to be sorted on year first for this to work.

Comment: I was aware of the plyr package and thought about using it. Thanks for showing me how it could be done.